# Bootstrap Fixed Navigation Bar doesn't work with asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been working with asp.net in constellation with mvc5 and bootstrap 3.7.7 for a while now, and that with no problems at all. Until now, I have run into problems in integrating a fixed navigation bar from bootstrap, here is my example that I refer on https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp, and I used that snippet in the standard generated "_Layout.cshtml" template that was given to me by default.

This is my current cshtml code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                @Html.ActionLink("navbar-brand", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>            
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li><a>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</a></li>
            <li><a>@Html.ActionLink("Property Groups", "Index", "PropertyGroups")</a></li>
            <li><a>@Html.ActionLink("Properties", "Index", "Property")</a></li>
            <li><a>@Html.ActionLink("Property Values", "Index", "PropertyValues")</a></li>
            <li><a>@Html.ActionLink("Upload CSV Files", "Index", "csvUpload")</a></li>
            <li><a>@Html.ActionLink("Glimpse", "Index", "glimpse.axd")</a></li>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

And what I get in my firefox browser is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7cNo.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is due to your nav bar links. See the @Html.ActionLink generates the anchor tag for you and you do not need to put it within an anchor tag.

So your current links look like this in HTML:

```
<li><a><a href="/Home/About">About</a></a></li>
```

Change your links to:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
```

This would produce this HTML result:

```
<li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
```

That is what you want. So just remove all the opening and closing anchor tags and it should be alright.